# How to add custom HTTP Header to JAX-RS response?

Tags: apache, cxf, jax-rs

I'm trying to add custom HTTP header to response in Apache CXF. I need to count MD5 from content and add it as a HTTP header. I tried to use ResponseHandler or Interceptor. My last try was

```
@Component
public class ResponseBPAuthFilter extends AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor {


   public ResponseBPAuthFilter() {
       super(Phase.MARSHAL_ENDING);
   }


   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message t) throws Fault {

       Map headers = CastUtils.cast((Map)t.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS));
       headers.put("Some-Header", Arrays.asList("test"));

   }

}
```

but it does nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Try to add `Response Object` as your return value where you can set Headers..

```
Response.ok(/* some entity */).header("CustomHeader", "CustomValue").build();
```

You don't need to use interceptors

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you can accomplish this using the CXF CachedOutputStream.

```
public class MD5OutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public MD5OutInterceptor () {
        super(Phase.MARSHAL);
    }

    public final void handleMessage(Message message) {


        OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        if (os == null) {
            return;
        }

        final CachedOutputStream cos = new CachedOutputStream(os);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        cos.writeCacheTo(baos);

        // calculate MD5
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] mdBytes = md.digest(baos);

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = (MetadataMap<String, Object>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);

        if (headers == null) {
            headers = new MetadataMap<String, Object>();
        }             

        headers.add("MD5-Header", new String(mdBytes));
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to configure your interceptor in the cxf configuration file:

```
<jaxrs:server>
    <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="md5OutInterceptor">
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="md5OutInterceptor" class="com.whatever.MD5OutInterceptor" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Check **CustomOutInterceptor.java** in folder  **src/systests/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/jaxrs/** 
from **cxf-2.3.3 source distribution** for a working demo:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.MetadataMap;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

public class MyOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public MyOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.MARSHAL);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = new MetadataMap<String, Object>();
        headers.putSingle("BookId", "123");
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
    }
}
```

I guess the code you posted as your last attempt is taken from [1](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html#JAX-RSFilters-Overridingresponsestatuscodeandheaders). Been trying this too, could not get it to work either...