# Apache CXF - Set HTTP header

Tags: apache, header, cxf, interceptor

I have to set some http header fields in a Apache CXF client:

I tried it via Interceptor:

```
    public class HttpHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private String userId;
    private String xAuthorizeRoles;
    private String host;


    public HttpHeaderInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.POST_PROTOCOL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        Map<String, List> headers = (Map<String, List>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
        try {
            System.out.println("HttpHeaderInterceptor Host: " + host + " UserId: " + userId + " X-AUTHORIZE-roles: " + xAuthorizeRoles);
            headers.put("Host", Collections.singletonList(host));
            headers.put("UserId", Collections.singletonList(userId));
            headers.put("X-AUTHORIZE-roles", Collections.singletonList(xAuthorizeRoles));
        } catch (Exception ce) {
            throw new Fault(ce);
        }
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setxAuthorizeRoles(String xAuthorizeRoles) {
        this.xAuthorizeRoles = xAuthorizeRoles;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
}
```

in my dynamic client class the methode:

```
public void setHttHeaderInterceptor(String userId, String xAuthorizeRoles){
    Client cxfClient = ClientProxy.getClient(this.abgWebServicePort);
    HttpHeaderInterceptor httpHeaderInterceptor = new HttpHeaderInterceptor();
    httpHeaderInterceptor.setHost("example.org");
    httpHeaderInterceptor.setUserId(userId);
    httpHeaderInterceptor.setxAuthorizeRoles(xAuthorizeRoles);
    cxfClient.getOutInterceptors().add(httpHeaderInterceptor);
}
```

is called before I invoke the remote service:

For each call the userId and the xAuthorizeRoles should vary but when I inspect by calls via tcpdump all calls have the same values in the header fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3165647/55452

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I Have solved my problem:

adding the interceptor via xml configuration:

```
<jaxws:client id="clientBean" serviceClass="org.example.service.ServicePortType"
              address="example.org/src/service/ServicePort">
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.example.interceptor.HttpHeaderInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

in the client class I altered setHttpHeaderInterceptor to

```
public void setHttpHeaderInterceptor(String userId, String xAuthorizeRoles){
    Client cxfClient = ClientProxy.getClient(this.servicePort);
    cxfClient.getRequestContext().put("HTTP_HEADER_HOST", "example.org");
    cxfClient.getRequestContext().put("HTTP_HEADER_USER_ID", userId);
    cxfClient.getRequestContext().put("HTTP_HEADER_X_AUTHORIZE-ROLES", xAuthorizeRoles);
}
```

the interceptor class

```
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        Map<String, List> headers = (Map<String, List>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
        try {
            headers.put("Host", Collections.singletonList(message.get("HTTP_HEADER_HOST")));
            headers.put("KD_NR", Collections.singletonList(message.get("HTTP_HEADER_KD_NR")));
            headers.put("X-AUTHORIZE-roles", Collections.singletonList(message.get("HTTP_HEADER_X_AUTHORIZE-ROLES")));
        } catch (Exception ce) {
            throw new Fault(ce);
        }
    }
```

and now it work's.

With this approach I can set HTTP-Header fields at runtime.

Comment: i need to get cxf header session_id and send it via axis2. then how to do that .?   
-thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have used :`Phase.POST_LOGICAL` instead of `Phase.POST`. This worked for me

Comment: Per the documentation, it didn't seem to be the phase for doing this; that being said, that modification did work around a problem where CXF seemed to be randomly ignoring the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet to copy a custom HTTP header (from the request) on the response in a single CXF out interceptor.

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
    // Get request HTTP headers
    Map<String, List<String>> inHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.getExchange().getInMessage().get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
    // Get response HTTP headers
    Map<String, List<String>> outHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
    if (outHeaders == null) {
        outHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, outHeaders);
    }
    // Copy Custom HTTP header on the response
    outHeaders.put("myCustomHTTPHeader", inHeaders.get("myCustomHTTPHeader"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If required to set standard HTTP header then it can be done using http conduit also.

```
<http-conf:conduit
        name="*.http-conduit">
<http-conf:client AllowChunking="false" AcceptEncoding="gzip,deflate" Connection="Keep-Alive"
 Host="myhost.com"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```