# how to read soap response header from JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-rs

[This is not work for me.Hadlers.xml get error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487114/retreiving-soap-header-on-jaxws-server-side)

Comment: how exactly is it not working? Add more details to the question

Comment: <javaee:handler-chains> get compile error cant identify the symbol

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31719808/edit) the question & add the details there

Comment: uh?, first of all, WHY do you need this?, don't you generate your classes with CXF? -> http://cxf.apache.org/download.html

Comment: yah i generated classes with CFX.but how do i get header values.I have message handler class but how do i access getHeader method

Comment: Ok, maybe this thread can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479396/apache-cxf-set-http-header

Comment: thanx.i got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes help to get soap header content

private List getHeaders() {

```
    MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();

    if (messageContext == null || !(messageContext instanceof WrappedMessageContext)) {

        return null;

    }
    Message message = ((WrappedMessageContext) messageContext).getWrappedMessage();

    List<Header> headers = CastUtils.cast((List<?>) message.get(Header.HEADER_LIST));

    return headers;

}
```